# How to use my reserved ngrok pro domain with a virtual host

Tags: wordpress, ngrok, laragon

Using Laragon, I've created a WordPress site on my local machine for testing a plugin I'm developing. Laragon creates virtual hosts for projects and I can access my wordpress site locally at wp001.test, which is normal since my project is named wp001.

If I run ngrok like so I can browse my site externally using the dynamically generated ngrok domain:

```
ngrok http -host-header=rewrite wp001.test:80
```

I signed up for a pro ngrok account so I could use a reserved domain name. I created my reserved domain name on the ngrok dashboard.

Now I can get ngrok to accept my reserved domain like so:

```
ngrok http -hostname=my-reserved-domain.ngrok.io 80
```

Then I can browse to `my-reserved-domain.ngrok.io` but it's taking me to the web root of the file system (`C:\laragon\www`) instead of making use of the virtual host.

How can I make ngrok use my reserved domain with the virutal host? I've read the ngrok docs but I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make this work by using an ngrok config file. The file looks like this:

```
web_addr: localhost:4041

# ngrok auth config
authtoken: your_token_goes_here

tunnels:
  your-tunnel-name:
    proto: http
    hostname: your-reserved-ngrok-domain.ngrok.io
    addr: 127.0.0.1:80

    # -------------------------
    # Additional options
    # -------------------------
    # auth: "username:password"
    host_header: your-virutal-host.com:80
    # inspect: true
    # bind_tls: true
```

Then starting ngrok and specifying the config file:

```
ngrok start -config=path/to/your/conf/file.yml --all
```